# Disable background process termination notification

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a way to disable console notifications about background processes having terminated? Typically, something like this is printed when I run a completely unrelated command:

```
[1]+  Done  some-command
```

I find it quite distracting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for your child processes exit codes then you can run them with `setsid <cmd>` or `nohup <cmd>` instead of `<cmd>&`. This will run them separately instead of in the background of the current console.

Answer (score 0):

Using `disown` to remove the job from the current shell:

`some-command & disown`

More about `disown` -> https://askubuntu.com/a/612106/191003

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I'm looking for, however, is a way to disable these notifications altogether, something similar to how MAILCHECK=0 works.